# How to access external hard drive from Ubuntu Shell and Python code

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hard-disk, path, directory-structure

I am running out of space in my local device. I have external hard disk. I want to point my python code to write to directory there. How can I know the full path for the hard disk?

I tried to go to `media` directory. I used `ls` and found only one directory with the same user name `x`. I `cd` to `x`, and found the hard disk name. When I try to `cd` to the hard disk name I get this message: `too many arguments`

```
x@x-device:/media$ ls
x
x@x-device:/media$ cd x
x@x-device:/media/x$ ls
'Seagate Backup Plus Drive'
x@x-device:/media/x$ cd Segate Backup Plus Drive
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Q: How to find the full path of a directory in an external hard disk? How can I open a file in my external hard disk in python program?

```
v = open("my_file_in_the_external_hard_disk.txt","r")
```

**EDIT:**
File system is: NTFS/exFAT/HPFS

**Edit:**
I changed the hard disk name to remove spaces. I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> x@x-device:/media/x$ cd Segate Backup Plus Drive bash: cd: too many
>   arguments

Your command did not work because you didn't quote the spaces. It has nothing to do with where the directory is physically located. A proper way to `cd` into a directory with spaces (or call any other command on it) would be

```
$ cd 'Segate Backup Plus Drive'
```

or

```
$ cd "Segate Backup Plus Drive"
```

or

```
$ cd Segate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive
```

You can save a lot of typing by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocomplete feature in Bash:

`$ cd S` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

will expand into

```
$ cd Segate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive
```